# Locking struct content

Tags: matlab, debugging, struct

I am hardcoding a GUI for tensile test analyses using Matlab.

When calling the GUI I decalare `Results` struct so contain all results from the analysis and I want to store it `.mat` file with all the data created during the analysis (stress-strain curves, dimensions, etc.)

The `Results.whatever` is declared when GUI is started to be `nan` and proper value is set in callbacks. When I make a typo it just appends new `Results.whtever` value without throwing any error, warning, whatever...

Is there some way, how to:

- Prevent new struct definition(s) in callback routines to happen. I.e. `Results.whtever=1` throws an error while `Results.whatever=1` do not.
- Edit the struct content rather redefining it I.e. `foo(Results.whtever,1)` throws an error while `foo(Results.whatever,1)` do not.

EDIT: code snippet

```
% GUI initiation (declaring nested variables)
function=runGUI
% code

Results.Rpt=nan;

% another code

  % Callback using nested variables Results and DataArray
  function PushFoo
  % more code
  RP=find(DataArray(:,11)>0.2,1,'first');
  Results.RPt=round(DataArray(RP,9));
  % yet another code
  end
end
```

Cut to the snippet; it doesn't look like an issue but as requests rise the code gets longer and longer.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about where you are making this typo, and how the value is currently being stored/used? In your callbacks you can use 'isfield' to make sure the field currently exists instead of adding a new one...

Answer (score 2):

1. No this isn't possible, you just need to check your code carefully for typos. You could check the number of fields to make sure that it's always what you expect but that's about it

   ```
   assert(numel(fieldnames(Results)) == 1, 'You have a typo or something')
   ```
2. Of course using `set` throws an error, it's not defined for the `struct` datatype. If this is a GUIDE GUI, then the easiest option for your GUI is to save the data within the `guidata` of the figure

   ```
   Results.whatever = 1;
   handles.Results = Results;

   % Save it in the GUI
   guidata(hObject, handles)
   ```

   Alternately, you can store it within the `UserData` property of your figure

   ```
   % Get the stored value
   Results = get(gcbf ,'UserData');

   % Change the value
   Results.whatever = 1;

   % Save it again
   set(gcbf, 'UserData', Results)
   ```
3. Another option would be to use a `handle` class rather than a `struct` which will be passed around by reference. I wrote [`structobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55773-structobj) which essentially creates a `handle` class that behaves similarly to `struct`.

Comment: Sorry for invalidating your `set` comment. I was about the functionality of `set` rather than using `set` itself.

Answer (score 1):

While I think #3 of [Suever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501288/locking-struct-content/43501334#43501334) would be most appropriate for a generic "results" data structure, another approach could be a custom data class:

```
classdef crowleydata < handle
    properties
        aproperty
        anotherproperty
    end

    methods
        function myObj = crowleydata(myObj)
            if nargout == 0
                % No instance if an output variable isn't specified
                clear myObj;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Which you could instantiate with your GUI initialization and store all of the desired data as properties of the class:

```
>> results = crowleydata();
>> results.aproperty = 2

results = 

  crowleydata with properties:

          aproperty: 2
    anotherproperty: []

>> results.thing = 5
No public property thing exists for class testcode.
```

The advantage to this approach is that you can [create methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html) specific to your data that you can utilize in any setting, like a plotting routine that the GUI can call rather than hardcoding the behavior into the GUI itself.

This approach also allows for type enforcement, if we were to change our `properties` block slightly:

```
properties
    aproperty@double        % Undocumented syntax, works >= R2012a (and probably older)
    anotherproperty double  % Documented syntax introduced in R2016a
end
```

We can get the following:

```
>> a = crowleydata();
>> a.aproperty = 2

a = 

  crowleydata with properties:

          aproperty: 2
    anotherproperty: []

>> a.aproperty = 'hi'
Error setting property 'aproperty' of class 'crowlydata':
Value must be 'double'.
```

Comment: Looks straightforward and robust. I think it is good approach for new project; I think I am too far now.

Comment: Other than adding one line to initialize there is no necessary change to your existing GUI code.